# Android build suddenly starts failing with : resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Our android build started failing all on its own without a single line change for 2 days now.

This is the error message:

> /Users/shroukkhan/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/ui-5.11.1.aar/baa8b66e2e52a0a50719f014fc3f1c32/res/values/values.xml:40:5-54: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>
> /Users/shroukkhan/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/ui-5.11.1.aar/baa8b66e2e52a0a50719f014fc3f1c32/res/values/values.xml:40:5-54: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

As I understand this is related to android support library version mismatch, so i have forced using same library version . However, the problem has persisted. Here is the root level build.gradle:

```
 buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } // Google's Maven repository
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
        classpath 'hu.supercluster:paperwork-plugin:1.2.7'
        classpath "gradle.plugin.me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.5.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }

        configurations.all {
           resolutionStrategy {
               // force certain versions of dependencies (including transitive)
               force 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
             eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
               if (details.requested.group == 'com.facebook.react' && details.requested.name == 'react-native') {
                 details.useVersion "0.38.0"
               }
             }
           }
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

task dependencyReportFile(type: DependencyReportTask) {
    outputFile = file('dependencies.txt')
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = "27.1.0"
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
    googlePlayServicesAnalyticsVersion = "16.0.4"

    envConfigFiles = [
      develop: ".env.develop",
      production: ".env.production",
      staging: ".env.staging",
      anycustombuildlowercase: ".env",
    ]
}

subprojects {
    if (project.name.contains('react-native-facebook-login') || project.name.contains('react-native-image-picker') ||
            project.name.contains('react-native-permissions') || project.name.contains('react-native-vector-icons') ) {
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
                maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }
            }
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 27
                buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
                supportLibVersion = "27.1.0"
                googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1" //<-- life save line?
            }
        }
    }
}

subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate{
        if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 27
                buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
                supportLibVersion = "27.1.0"
                googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
            }

            android {
                lintOptions {
                    tasks.lint.enabled = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.facebook.react' && details.requested.name == 'react-native') {
                    details.useVersion "0.38.0" // Your real React Native version here
                }
            }
        }
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    }
}
```

And here is the app level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.3.1"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.5.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'hu.supercluster.paperwork'

paperwork {
    set = [
            OKKAMI_APP_VERSION: "2.0",
            buildTime         : buildTime("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "GMT"),
            gitSha            : gitSha(),
            gitTag            : gitTag(),
            gitInfo           : gitInfo(),
            gitBranch         : gitBranch()
    ]
}

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
        debug                  : ".env.develop",
        release                : ".env.production",
        staging                : ".env.staging",
        sixsensesDevelop       : ".evn.sixsenses.develop",
        sixsensesProduction    : ".env.sixsenses.production",
        cirqProduction         : ".env.cirq.production",
        nextDevelop            : ".env.next.develolp",
        nextProduction         : ".env.next.production",
        anycustombuildlowercase: ".env.develop",
]
apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    def versionPropsFile = file('../../build')
    def versionBuild
    def paperworkfile = file('src/main/assets/paperwork.json')

    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
        String ret = reader.readLine();
        fin.close();
        versionBuild = ret.split("\n")[0];
    } else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read build file")
    }

    ext.autoIncrementBuildNumber = {

        if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
            def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
            versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
            versionBuild = versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger() + 1
            versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'] = versionBuild.toString()
            versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)
        } else {
            throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
        }
    }

    def props = new Properties()
    def configFile
    def prefix = "OKKAMI"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.okkami.android.app"
        buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
        compileSdkVersion 28

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }

        multiDexEnabled true

        manifestPlaceholders = [devUrlCustomScheme: "okkamidevelop", stagingUrlCustomScheme: "okkamistaging", prodUrlCustomScheme: "okkami"]
        renderscriptTargetApi 23
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.okkami.android.app"

        javaCompileOptions { annotationProcessorOptions { includeCompileClasspath = true } }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }


    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "8g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
    }

    android {
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility 1.8
            targetCompatibility 1.8
        }
    }


    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }

        debug { //sign debug apk as well...
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/gson/FieldAttributes.class'
        exclude '.readme'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {

        // OKKAMI
        develop {
            applicationId "com.okkami.android.app.dev"
            versionCode = versionBuild.toInteger()
            versionName = '2.0.' + versionBuild
        }

        staging {
            applicationId "com.okkami.android.app.staging"
            versionCode = versionBuild.toInteger()
            versionName = '2.1.' + versionBuild
        }

        production {
            applicationId "com.okkami.android.app"
            versionCode = versionBuild.toInteger()
            versionName = '2.2.' + versionBuild
        }


        // Six Senses
        sixsensesDevelop {
            applicationId "com.okkami.android.sixsenses.app.dev"
            versionCode = versionBuild.toInteger()
            versionName = '2.0.' + versionBuild
        }

//        sixsensesStaging {
//            applicationId "com.okkami.android.sixsenses.app.staging"
//            versionCode = versionBuild.toInteger()
//            versionName = '2.1.' + versionBuild
//        }
//
        sixsensesProduction {
            applicationId "com.okkami.android.sixsenses.app"
            versionCode = versionBuild.toInteger()
            versionName = '2.2.' + versionBuild
        }


        // Cirq
        cirqDevelop {
            applicationId "com.cirq.android.app.dev"
            versionCode = versionBuild.toInteger()
            versionName = '2.0.' + versionBuild
        }

        cirqProduction {
            applicationId "com.cirq.android.app"
            versionCode = versionBuild.toInteger()
            versionName = '2.2.' + versionBuild
        }

        // Next
        nextDevelop {
            applicationId "com.okkami.android.next.app.dev"
            versionCode = versionBuild.toInteger()
            versionName = '2.0.' + versionBuild
        }

        nextProduction {
            applicationId "com.okkami.android.next.app"
            versionCode = versionBuild.toInteger()
            versionName = '2.2.' + versionBuild
        }

    }
    compileSdkVersion = 27

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }

}

def supportLibraryVersion = "27.1.0"
def firebaseMessagingVersion = "17.3.2"

dependencies {
    compile(project(':react-native-camera')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-tasks'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-stats'
    }
    compile project(':react-native-device-brightness')
    implementation project(':react-native-battery')
    implementation project(':react-native-fast-image')
    implementation project(':react-native-bluetooth-status')
    implementation project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile 'com.github.nisrulz:easydeviceinfo-base:2.4.0'
    implementation(project(':react-native-audio-streaming'))
            {
                exclude module: 'support-v4'
            }
    implementation project(':react-native-restart')
    implementation project(':react-native-wheel-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-tcp')
    implementation project(':react-native-exit-app')
    implementation project(':react-native-aws-cognito-js')
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation project(':react-native-fs')
    implementation project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation project(':react-native-blur')
    implementation project(':react-native-geocoder')
    implementation project(':react-native-facebook-login')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-tasks'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-stats'
    }
    implementation project(':react-native-i18n')
    implementation project(':react-native-config')
    implementation project(':okkami-sdk')
    implementation project(':react-native-permissions')
    implementation project(':okkami-react-sdk')
    // Line SDK
    compile(name: 'line-sdk-4.0.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile "com.android.support:customtabs:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile('io.smooch:core:5.11.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-tasks'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-stats'
    }
    compile('io.smooch:ui:5.11.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-tasks'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-stats'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }

//  compile 'io.smooch:core:5.14.2'
//  compile 'io.smooch:ui:5.14.2'
    // Libraries imported by Smooch
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${firebaseMessagingVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.3"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.3'
    compile 'com.pusher:push-notifications-android:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.37.0'
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:4.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'hu.supercluster:paperwork:1.2.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.shiraji:butai-java:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    // Lombo
//  implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16'
    // HockeyApp
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:5.1.1'
    // Google Analytics
    implementation(project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-tasks'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-stats'
    }
    // Badges for Android
    compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.16@aar'
    compile files('libs/AndroidRuntimePermissions.jar')
    // Webview for Android
    implementation project(':RNWebView')
    //compile project(':react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation')
    implementation project(':react-native-smart-splashscreen')

    implementation project(':openkeysdk-release')
    /*guava library used for salto*/
    implementation('com.google.guava:guava:18.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    //slf4j,bouncycastle and mixpanel used for assa
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.21'
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.58'
    implementation('com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.+') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
//OKC
    implementation 'com.clj.fastble:FastBleLib:2.3.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1'


    compile project(path: ':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(path: ':RNMaterialKit')
    compile project(path: ':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation(project(path: ':react-native-device-info')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-tasks'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-stats'
    }
    compile project(':react-native-orientation')
    compile project(':react-native-full-screen')
    implementation(project(':react-native-play-sound')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-tasks'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-stats'
    }
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0"

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1"
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1"
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1"
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0"
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

task dependencyReportFile(type: DependencyReportTask) {
    outputFile = file('dependencies.txt')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

I have tracked it down to most likely candidate : io.smooch:ui:5.11.1 ( because the error states : .gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/ui-5.11.1.aar/baa8b66e2e52a0a50719f014fc3f1c32/res/values/values.xml:40:5-54: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found. ) . However, no solution proposed online has been working.

Does anyone have any idea whats going on ?

Edit : link to excerpt from dependency tree: https://pastebin.com/raw/YNHWkf5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `fontVariationSettings` attribute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#fontVariationSettings) was added in API Level 28.

Set your `compileSdkVersion` to 28 or higher to be able to use libraries that reference this attribute.

Comment: I have tried that. then it fails with:  AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty. infact the codebase is old and it needs to stay at api level 27 or lower ( supposed to run on our own specific android tablets )

Comment: @ShroukKhan: Then you are going to have to track down where the `ui-5.11.1` dependency is coming from (e.g., run a Gradle dependency report). Then, either remove the dependency or force the build to use some version that is compatible with the rest of your codebase.

Comment: i have added a link to dependency tree here: https://pastebin.com/raw/YNHWkf5D , nothing really stands out

Comment: @ShroukKhan: It would appear to be `io.smooch:ui:5.11.1`, based on the artifact name and version number.

Comment: yes, but looking at the dependency tree of io.smooch:ui:5.11.1 at https://pastebin.com/raw/YNHWkf5D ..its not very obvious which one of its internal dependencies are causing it

Comment: @ShroukKhan: It is not an internal dependency. `io.smooch:ui:5.11.1` itself has the attribute that requires `compileSdkVersion 28`. You need to remove that dependency or switch to some version that works with `compileSdkVersion` of `27` or lower

Comment: removing the library is not an option unfrotunately. however, this particular version has been working with api level 27 for nearly an year now. wondering why it suddenly broke

Comment: @ShroukKhan: I can't answer that. You might talk to the developers of the library. The error message claims that this attribute is in that AAR. If the library is open source, you might rummage through the source code to try to confirm that a resource in that library is referring to this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Update your fb dependency version-

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.11.0'
```

and you have to add following line to android/gradle.properties:

```
facebookSdkVersion=5.11.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Change :

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.11.1'
```

TO:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.11.0'
```

**Located in app.gradle file**

Clean project and Rebuild

Happy Coding!